# Customize compose message in open source zimbra?

Tags: javascript, open-source, zimbra

I would like to add a dropdown list with a few options to the compose mail entity.

When clicking on an option on the dropdown.. Some text would be inserted into the content of the mail.. Uneditable of course, but that's details..

I thought that I could just add some javascript to the compose mail option, and get the job done..

My question is, can I do that? If yes, maybe an indication of what files should be changed, or if I can do it in a separate file, where the new js file should be added?

If it's not possible just with javascript alone, any indications on how I could do this? :)

A photo denoting my needs -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsvMR.jpg

Thank you for your time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutly possible. You need to build a zimlet to do that. 
A Zimlet is a kind of a plugin that enables features in the zimbra webmail.

Developpement guide :
http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimlet_Developers_Guide:Introduction

You should check this zimlet : https://gallery.zimbra.com/type/zimlet/email-templates